# How to attach a javaagent to all java applets

Tags: java, applet, javaagents

I wrote a sample java agent that creates a "hello world" file in a specific place. I want it to run whenever any java applet is run (definitely including ones I didn't write myself.) How do I do that?

My agent works when I run it manually from the command line (as in, running another java file with the agent attached to it.) On the automatic front, I tried going into the java configuration panel -> Java -> View -> JRE Configuration Settings -> setting the optional arguments to attach my agent, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I browse with FF to someplace that makes me run a java applet but no file is created.

I'm guessing I'm missing something basic here, because when I try to google this people all around various forums seem to answer it as if it's the most trivial thing: "just use -javaagent, read more about it in this (link)."

If it helps at all, this is the optional parameter I add in the configuration panel (which works when I use it manually):
-javaagent:C:\Users\admin\workspace\poc\bin\poc\myagent.jar

Update: I found out I can set an environment variable (JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS) to -javaagent:(agentpath). Once again it works flawlessly with local java applications, but now when I browse over to a webpage with an applet, firefox auto-closes itself. IE declares the webpage broken. Chrome doesn't even display the applet. The agent itself at this point does nothing - it just has an empty premain method. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the environment variable JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS=-javagent:(path) is right.

My error was that I misconstructed the .jar file. Once I fixed that (simply used the jar.exe tool to make my .jar) it worked properly - locally and on all applets via firefox. Until then, that was what caused firefox to either hang or crash when encountering an applet.